# Express server basic example not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, remote-server

I have node v7.4.0 installed on my remote server.  I've installed the latest version of express which is 4.14.0 and I've set up `index.js` in my `public_html`.  `index.js` is a copy of the official test online:

```
const express = require('express')  
const app = express()  
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (request, response) => {  
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

When I run `node index.js` while in `public_html`, I get the expected results: `server is listening on 3000`.  When I go to my server's domain name address or IP address on port 3000, I just get that it is "Connecting" and then it fails saying it took too long to respond (plus no response in the command line).  What can I look into to fix this?

Comment: perhaps your host is blocking ports?

Comment: Make use of es5 instead of es6 to debug

Comment: Why would that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like nothing is wrong with your code. It may be a firewall/antivirus; additionally, Try using another browser like Firefox. Make sure to use the loopback ip 127.0.0.1:3000 or localhost:3000 (same thing).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of the proxy. After disabling proxy for intranet, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of the firewall settings. I added private network access and then it worked fine.